# How to use AJAX, PHP, and Google App Engine together?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-app-engine

I have seen answers for this for Python, but not PHP. I have two select boxes, one select box is populated with a list of companies from an API call. When a user selects one of the companies, I want a second select box to be populated with the locations of that company.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: APP-NAME
version: 150115
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php
  secure: always

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: ewme/images/favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: ewme/css
  application_readable: true

- url: /images
  static_dir: ewme/images
  application_readable: true

- url: /js
  static_dir: ewme/js
  application_readable: true

- url: /ajax_request
  script: /ewme/scripts/ajax/request.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  secure: always
```

My php code in the php file that renders the html.

```
$companies = AjaxRequest::getCompanies();
$companies = json_decode($companies,true);
$cos = array();
foreach ($companies['companies'] as $co) {
    $cos[$co['company_code']] = strtoupper($co['company_code']);
}
```

... the html that is rendered...

```
<td>
    <label for="company_code">Company</label>
    <select name="company_code" id="company_code" onchange="sendAjax(&quot;/ajax_request&quot;,new Array(&quot;company_code&quot;),&quot;&amp;req=getCompanyLocations&quot;);">
</td>
```

The scripts/ajax.request.php file:

```
<?php 
$_POST['ajax']=true;
require_once('../../../env.php');
$current_user = Auth::getLoggedInUser();
$content="";
if (isset($_REQUEST['req']) &&   method_exists("AjaxRequest",$_REQUEST['req'])) {
    $r=$_REQUEST['req'];
    $ar = new AjaxRequest();
    $content=$ar->{$r}($_REQUEST);
}
echo $content;
```

From my JavaScript function "sendAjax" I keep getting this error `500 "<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Auth' not found in <b>/Users/Katrina/APP-NAME/ewme/scripts/ajax/request.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
" "error" "Internal Server Error"`

I tried including the files individually, which worked, but I would have to basically include all the files from my project. My env.php file includes my config.php, which has my spl_autoload_register(); function, so I'm not sure why it isn't working? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Figured this out myself. If anyone wants the answer, feel free to let me know and I'll post what I did.

Comment: It would be helpful for someone in the future who might get to your question by googling a similar problem they're having to see a possible solution right away rather than asking you and waiting for a reply. 

Also, a minor suggestion, you could keep your `app.yaml`'s 'handlers' section a lot more readable and smaller by storing your static files into a single `/static` folder creating one handler for that and leaving the `url: /.*` (no need for the `url: /` handler) thus having only 2 handlers instead of 7.

Comment: @MihailRussu I planned on posting the answer, it's just long and I didn't have time. Will post it when I have time. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any other benefit to that other than having the app.yaml file be smaller. Does it help with load time or anything?

Comment: No, there aren't any other benefits other than the readability of `app.yaml`. If there was a performance/load time improvement - it would be so insignificant that it wouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: @GreeKatrina - Could you post the solution please? I'm struggling with the similar situation